# Org agenda - edit the headline itself

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

From Org Agenda view, I can do several things like reschedule, reprioritize, tag, etc.

How do I edit the headline itself from the org agenda view? Or it can not be done?

Comment: Well, the underlying `.org` file is a `<Tab>` `org-agenda-goto` or `<Return>` `org-agenda-switch-to` away, the former in the other window, the latter replaces the agenda view. You could do edits with `B` `org-agenda-bulk-action` and `f` but that sounds too far fetched http://orgmode.org/manual/Agenda-commands.html

Comment: @p_wiersig I agree with `TAB` or `RET`. But there is a specific section on Remote Editing [here](http://orgmode.org/manual/Agenda-commands.html) So I thought out-of-the-box it would provide an option to edit the heading itself